# How do I specify Normals using GL_INT_2_10_10_10_REV in a VBO array?

Tags: opengl

I have normals which are (x,y,z) as 3 floats, and I want to pack these into a VBO array as GL_INT_2_10_10_10_REVs in order to reduce memory consumption on the graphics card. Can anyone provide an example of how to do this in C++ / C#?

The OpenGL documentation says you can do this - 
https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification_Best_Practices

However, I can't find any examples of how to place the three floats (which can be positive or negative) into the single packed 4 byte structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [the spec](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec45.core.pdf), section 10.3.8, "Packed Vertex Data Formats", page 343:

> For `INT_2_10_10_10_REV`, the x, y and z components are represented as 10-bit signed two’s complement integer values and the w component is represented as a 2-bit signed two’s complement integer value.

Comment: Thank you - the charts there make it pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to pack them in a bitfield that looks something like:

```
struct norm{
    int a:2; 
    int Z:10; 
    int y:10; 
    int X:10; //order may need to be different
}
```

ensure the field you put in are scaled to `-512` to `511`